# Dynamically adjust div background-image when window is resized

Tags: html, css

```
.step-1-4 {
  background:url('../images/gadget-4-sprite.png') 
  no-repeat; width:950px; 
  height:70px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Above is the CSS for a div I have which holds a background-image. I have set the height and width of the div the same as the dimensions of the image. The problem i'm having is when the window is re-sized for example less than the width of the image, it gets cut off.

Is there a solution whereby I can style the CSS in such a way that the div re-sizes along with the image inside it. I have tried making the width of the div 100%, which re-sizes the div correctly, however the image still does not re-size. Maybe if this is not a good solution, then how can this be achieved using an `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

use `background-size:cover;` or `background-size:100% 100%;`

so your css will be ::

```
.step-1-4 {
  background:url('../images/gadget-4-sprite.png') no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%; /*..or  cover ...*/
  width:950px; 
  height:70px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```